# LibreOffice Calc changes letter from uppercase to lowercase under certain circumstances

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, spell-check

I want to enter `SXer` into a field, however the `X` gets automatically converted to `x`. If I only write `SX`, the `X` stays the way it is. If I write `SXEr`, all letters stay as they are. But somehow I can't write `SXer`. How can I do it?

Comment: It looks like you have auto-correct at work for capitalization.  Check main menu: Tools | Options | Language Settings | Writing Aids | Options window on the right side of the dialog box.

Comment: @fixer1234: That was it. Weird how it behaves.

Comment: Is there a way to undo single changes like this without disabling *all* of autocorrect?

Comment: @fixer1234 What is the actual name of the option, in that Options list? In LibreOffice 5.2.3.3 I don't see an option that helps with this.

Comment: @DavidFaure, I've got v5.1.1.3 loaded now.  It looks like the options may have changed.  I'm no longer seeing an option to toggle auto-correction of capitalization in general.  For this specific case, I noticed there's an option: Tools | Auto-correct options | Correct TWo INitial CApitals.

Comment: On `LibreOffice 5.1.6.2` I tried unticking the `Tools | Auto-correct options | Correct TWo INitial CApital` option and the `Check uppercased words` but none of these helped, and my cell keeps changing my word `Organisation` into the word `organisation`.

Comment: @Stephane probably no use to you several months on, but I think I solved your issue; see my answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue like this in LibreOffice Calc 5.4.3.2.

In a sheet of people's names, it kept changing Amanda back to amanda. It may have been because the cell to the left contained amanda.surname@domain.com in lower case.

The solution was to deactivate the Option: Tools > AutoInput

Answer (score 0):

I was able to prevent this behavior by unchecking the following box:

Top menu bar> Tools> AutoCorrect Options ...>  "Correct TWo INitial CApitals"

This behavior seems unrelated to the AutoInput setting for me.